# SSRS column chart hide labels on x-axis conditionally

Tags: reporting-services

How to hide SSRS x-axis conditionally on column chart. If values are zero i dont want to display the label on x-axis. 
data values - x-axis shows category group -filing types
values - filing count

Please check the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the label format property. I know that you can set the Number format to Custom and do something like:

```
=IIF(Fields!HasPrefix.Value,Fields!Prefix.Value," #0","No Prefix #0")
```

(This is the ChartAxis.LabelsFormat property if you have the axis selected. If you bring up the "Chart Axis Dialog" then this can be found on the Number listview item's format field.

I bet there is a way to use a format specifier to make it null or ""

Comment: As you said i have tried this =IIF(Fields!FilingCount.Value= 0," #0","No Prefix #0")but its not working. In the screen shot which i have pasted i want to hide Unknown label as its has zero values.

Comment: If you use #0 then the value will be what is in the dataset. I was thinking you could use something like 0:#%;;' ', note: this will return N and -N when the value is 1 and -1. That is the only thing I can think of.